# Error BC3002 when publish to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, publish

I am developing an ASP.NET web site using VS2015 that works on my local host.  Once I publish it to Azure, I get the attached error.[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaWfo.jpg)

As it works with no error on my local drive and I can pick at the class definition from the error line, so I am not sure what could have caused the issue once I publish the project to Azure:

[Error Line and the "Missing Object" definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTSr9.jpg)

In addition, I see the following errors although the programs run it may give clues to the solution but I do not know what I need to add and were:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdvZ7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and pictures you provided, it seems you problem you are facing is "**Could not load file or assembly after publish to Azure app service**".

It is a very big problem and it may casued by many things. Here are some workarounds you could refer to:

1.Right click your project and choose `Properties`. Set the "GoogleObject" referenced assembly **Copy Local to True**.
You need to make sure that all files are located in your bin folder of your web app.

2.Try to deploy your website content manully to Azure **via KUDU or FTP client** and find out whether it works of not.

3.Manually **delete** all the files you had in wwwroot and **redeploy** the app or click "**Remove additional files at destination**" when you publish setting.

Comment: 1.  I have the Copy Local set to True for GoogleObject, still the deployment did not work
2.  I never deployed manully a web site to Azure and I will need to read on how to perform it.

Comment: 1.  I have the Copy Local set to True for GoogleObject, still the deployment still did not work
2.  I never deployed manually a web site to Azure and I will need to read on how to perform it.
3.  I checked the "Remove additional files flag" and still got the error during deployment to Azure.

Not sure if you saw the errors under the screen print titled:
"enter image description here"  Nor sure if this is part of the same issue or how to solve it as the reference it is asking me to add looks strange (generated name by the system?).  Although it has the errors, the website runs OK on my PC

Comment: I published a number of the files (right click and selected the Publish Option) that I had errors on and now the Azure is working.  Not sure why the automatic process did not work to identify and publish them but for now it is all good.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You mean when you first publish your website it not working and after you configure something it works?

Comment: Have you do some changes with your configuration? If yes, could show me more details? thanks.

Comment: I followed the errors and published each file that gave me error when trying to publish the project by selecting it and publishing it alone.  Not sure if it make sense but for now, I can publish the project itself.